# Saving the date in internal storage and reading it later to compare it with current date

Tags: java, android

the application i'm working on is about letting the user participate only one time a day so first lines of the code are

```
if(datar.equals("-1")){
    anim(se);
}
```

it mean if the user open the app for the first time my main function anim(se) should work after that the variable datar will change and i will read it every time the user open the app so i want to add a second part to the if statement check if it have been passed 24h since the last time the user try the function anim(se) what i want is somthing like that

```
if(datar.equals("-1")){
    anim(se);
}
else
{
    if( "current date"-"last time the user use anim(se)">="24h")
         anim(se);
    else
       "the user still have to wait"
}
```

to do that i tried to save the date in anim(se)

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss");
Calendar last = Calendar.getInstance();
String dt = formatter.format(last);

try {
     FileOutputStream outputStream = openFileOutput("data", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     outputStream.write(dt.getBytes());
     outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

but i was having a problem here the app force to cloce .. :3

and i am sure that the rest of the code of reading the date and compare it with the current date is wrong too !

```
Calendar now,last = Calendar.getInstance();
String dt="";
        try {
            FileInputStream inputStream = openFileInput("date");
            BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                total.append(line);
            }
            r.close();
            inputStream.close();
            dt = total.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        java.util.Date lasta = null;
        try {
             lasta = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss").parse(dt);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        last.setTime(lasta);
        long diff = now.getTimeInMillis() - last.getTimeInMillis();

      if(datar.equals("-1")){
            anim(se);
        }else
       {
           if(diff>7200)
                anim(se);
       }
```

any idea how to do that :) ?

Answer (score 1):

Just use SharedPreferences. You do not need a separate file to store this information.

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("pref_name", MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putString("time", "put_your_time_here");
editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with these: where prefs is your sharedpreferences object and instead of boolean you pass him a string has value

```
    private void savePreferences(String key, boolean value) {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putBoolean(key, value);
        editor.commit();
    }

    private boolean loadSavedPreferences() {
        prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        return prefs.getBoolean("hasDataToSync", false);
    }
```